# Wrong behaviour/Bug in delphi2010 "extract method"

Tags: delphi, refactoring, delphi-2010

Im facing this issue when i try to extract a methode in the if statement. i couldnt find any reported bug on it.

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: integer;
  b: boolean;
begin
  if true then
    x := 8    //********************** i try to extract this line
  else
    x := 6;

  showmessage(inttostr(x));
end;
```

the result i get is:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: integer;
  b: boolean;
begin
  if true then
    newMethode
  else
    x := 6;

  showmessage(inttostr(x));
end;
```

and the new Methode is:

```
procedure TForm1.newMethode;
var
  x: Integer;
begin
  x := 8;
end;
```

Can anybody check how is the behaviour on Delphi XE? anybody knows if it was reported?

Comment: +1 for bringing up an interesting subject. But I believe that's a perfectly correct extraction.

Comment: @Cosmin: I don't. It should have been `procedure NewMethod(var x: Integer); begin x := 6; end;`. X should not be a local variable.

Comment: @Cosmin its wrong, x has the some undefined value instead of 8, this is not the usual behaviour of the extract methode in delphi2010, usually x should be given as a var parameter as Rudy mentioned.

Comment: Based on what rules should the `x` be a `var` parameter? Why not a function returning an Integer? What should happen if the selected block used 20 local variables? What I'm saying is that you can't talk about correctness unless you define it first. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Refactoring_Overview) only says `... the margin of error is small ...`. It doesn't define the rules of refactoring.

Comment: @Cosmin based on the Behaviour one used to when using this funcionality with D2010. losing the value of a variable and changing the output as a part of the refactoring is an error that should be fixed in my opinion.

Comment: Extract method refactoring should not change the effects of the code. Since the original code set the x in the original method, the extracted part should do the same, by making x a var parameter and calling newMethod(x); in the original location. One can argue that an extracted method like this is rather useless, but if it extracts, it should do it right.

Comment: @Cosmin: extract method apparently always produces procedures. So it should use a var parameter. Of course returning an integer would have done too, but that is not how this refactoring works, in Delphi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the "Extract Method" refactoring.

As an alternative, you might want to use the "Extract Method" refactoring from [ModelMaker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html) refactoring tool. At EUR 99, it is a [relatively cheap](http://www.modelmakertools.com/order/newlicenses.html) tool that works from Delphi 5 onward, and the [recent 9.0.5 updates](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/history/mmx905.html) have vastly improved their Extract Method refactoring so much that I haven't used the Delphi built-in one for quite a while.

Two great benefits:

- it launches the method-editor dialog where you can change and reorder parameters, which are then reflected in the extracted and calling code
- it leaves the original code in a (* *) comment just in case something fails, or you need to reference it

In addition, it places bookmarks (numbered 7, 8 and 9) in the code for easy navigation between the extracted code and the call site.

Highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks, ill take a look at it, although its not up to me but i can suggest it ... does it extract to functions to or only procedures?

Comment: It does both functions and procedures: just give the result a type and you get a function.

Comment: I recommend ModelMaker Code Explorer!

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer about extract method at [Oracle Blogs Entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/extract_method_introduce_variable_introduce)

Comment: How dos this answer the question?